# IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3 (Mac) update CVS with wrong encoding

Tags: java, intellij-idea, encoding, cvs

After doing a :

VCS --> CVS --> Update project

my windows-1252 files (.sql and .java for example) are coming with strange unrecognized characters (probably UTF-8 or whatever)

I have specified in :

Preferences --> Editor --> File Encoding

the **IDE Encoding** and **Project Encoding** to **windows-1252**
the **Transparent native-to-ascii** is not checked

Please help me !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDEA allows selecting the encoding of the file with the selector in the right lower corner. You could switch the encoding, and IDE should offer to convert the opened file.